# search an ntfs partition for files from linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, search, ntfs, find

My Linux system has an NTFS disk attached to it. How can I search for all *.txt files on the NTFS partition using Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would mount the drive with `mount -tntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt` (assuming your drive is at /dev/sdb, and /mnt is a suitable mount point.

Then I'd use `find /mnt -name *.txt`.  This isn't the fastest way, but it should work.

Comment: You might not need to, but it is probably safest to escape the * to prevent the shell from globbing it.

Comment: @slartibartfast: I don't believe it's necessary, but thanks for pointing it out; it's good to know if the results don't come out as expected.

BTW, I know you must get this a lot, but I personally found the fjords rather delightful.

Answer (score 0):

After mounting it, just navigate to the disk's root using nautilus (Ubuntu's default file manager) and search by clicking the looking glass. Then type in "*.txt".

Comment: That doesn't search directories.